# Provisioning profile "xyz" doesn't support the Wallet capability

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, ios10, wallet

Before updating xcode i was working on a project and everything was fine. Now once i updated my Xcode to Version 8.0 The same project keeps on giving me error regarding Code signing i have set the profiles for both debug and release versions and here is the error i am getting during code signing

```
 "Provisioning profile "xyz" doesn't support the Wallet capability"
```

Searched the Web and dint find any proper solution i know i can enable the wallet from store listing but i dont want to use it for now. Any help will be much appreciated

Thanks in advance
Regards
Usman

Answer (score 0):

I had some issues when upgrading to 8 as well, but I solved most of them by deleting Xcode i.e the upgraded one and installing it from scratch.

After this re-authenticate your developer profile from Xcode-> Preferences->Account.

Then re-Download your provisioning profiles again.

All should work fine!!

Comment: But i have installed it from scratch didnt updated it

Comment: got to your https://developer.apple.com profile -> Provisioning Profiles and Edit. Your should see and option to add Wallet in the properties check box